# razer_hydra: One controller working fine, other one extremely jittery

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just received a razer_hydra controller and tested it with the [razer_hydra](http://wiki.ros.org/razer_hydra) node. Setup was easy and one of the two controllers works as expected. The other one, however, behaves very erratic. If I perform a pure translation with it, the corresponding tf frames rotate, translate and jump around. Is this a known effect that can be fixed somehow, or is one of my controller units simply broken?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90971/razer_hydra:-one-controller-working-fine,-other-one-extremely-jittery/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2013-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had this problem when using two hydra controllers next to each other. If you only have one, it could be interference with an electromagnetic field that comes from somewhere else. Try using the hydra in another place to test this. Otherwise, it might just be broken.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0